# Folder Name and Category Name Wordpress

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, htaccess, 404-error

I have URLs that need have the old URL for download files.

Before, it has 2 separate website. The MAIN and the PORTAL website.

```
http://www.website.org
http://www.website.org/portal
```

I want both websites under in one admin page. So I did and make "PORTAL" as CATEGORY and it works well.

The problem is, I have "404 Not Found" page whenever I tried to view the PDF files. The files are now in:

```
website/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/31/
```

before:

```
website/portal/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/31/
```

Since I made PORTAL as category, I deleted the "PORTAL" folder.

How can I make the URL path or what to change in the admin page or in .htaccess file to still have the OLD url? I cannot change the URL to the new one since most of the files are link to other websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

This is the clean way using .htaccess. Put this at the top of your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 301 /portal/wp-content/uploads/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1
</IfModule>
```

### Option 2

This is a bit brute-force and I therefore wouldn't recommend it, but I include it here for completeness.

Just copy all files in `website/portal/wp-content/uploads` to `website/wp-content/uploads/` manually

Comment: Thanks kraftner, Option 1 works like a charm. Same URL in other website. Thank you again.